# How would a renaissance andean native civilization look like?

Tags: magic, culture, technological-development

The Karkalá Confederation is one of the main factions in my world. They were muiscas and incas teleported by Bochica to survive. They live on an archipelago with several mountain formations with two plateaus. There are three powers: the Zipa, the Zaque and the Iraca.

[image]

Zipazgo is the economic and political power of the Confederation. They praise the moon and the Zipa controls the North and economics, trading routes, laws and diplomatic relationships.

Zacazgo is the militar power of the confederation. They praise the sun and the Zaque is the one who controls the Southern and Eastern territories; he also the one who leads the conquer assaults, controls the Hatun Amaru (giant snake) and administrates the army (recruitment, training, weaponary, etc.)

Iraca is the descendant of Bochica himself and the religious figure. He's like the Pope of the Karkalá's confederation. He rules the west and is the one who choose the güechas in the holy lake. The holy lands of the west are where the magic clothing, runic tatoos and holy weapons come from. Zipazgo and Zacazgo must give some gold and their best textiles to the Iraca.

[image]

They have low steel reserves, so they prefer tumbaga (a gold, silver and copper) to make their standard weapons while only güechas have access to high quality steel armor. They also use titanoboas as coastal weapon, taking down small ships with them. They have horses, but the lands are too mountainous to be used effectively so they use planes. Yes, planes. However, they can only move using wind magic and it lasts almost half hour and they can't carry a lot of weight (more than one ton).

[image]

But their most powerful technique is goldsmithing. They can create several magic gold jewels with unique powers.

They also trade gold, salt, silver, goldsmithing and textiles.

My question is, how would a 'renaissance' civilization with muisca/inca influence look like? I've never seen something similar so i have that question.

Comment: I am afraid this is opinion based. To paraphrase a finance statement: past appearance is not warranty of future look.

Comment: your description look renaissance enough to me, or you want it to be more like europe type renaissance?

Comment: Would you mind providing image attribution, it's in the site terms and conditions of use.

Comment: I am not at all certain that I understand what you want. First of all, the Renaissance is a purely European phenomenon. Other civilizations did not have anything similar. Culturally, the foundation of European Renaissance is the re-discovery and re-valorification of the classical culture; other civilizations either never forgot their ancient roots (e.g., the Chinese or the Indians), or else simply did not have the required time depth (e.g., the Incas or the Aztecs). Second, the actual for-real Inca civilization was contemporary with the European Renaissance...

Comment: By the way, *nobody* has "steel reserves". Steel is an alloy of iron with carbon and possibly others. Due to the way our planet was put together, iron ore deposits are extremely common. Any landmass large enough to support an advanced civilization will certainly have some iron ore deposits.

Answer (score 3):

The European Renaissance involved rediscovering Greek and Roman culture, philosophy, etc, shortly after the Black Death dramatically thinned the population. The culture you described does seem to be isolated from their origins, but there is the little matter of how that cultural ancestry can be revitalized. The Inca did use Quipus as a form of writing, but it isn't clear if this was anywhere near extensive enough for discovering some Quipus tapestry in an acetics affects to serve that purpose.

There might be a mechanism, though, given your premise. In our history, many Quipus were destroyed during Colonization, and it's suggested they were mostly for record-keeping or simple messages. But if those who were teleported to your setting brought more culturally relevant Quipus with them, then we wouldn't know about them here. Even if Quipus were only for record-keeping in our world, the somewhat similar system of Wampum strings used by the Haudenosaunee were used for things ranging from historical records to ceremonial recitations to poetry, so the medium isn't inherently unusable for this sort of thing.

For it to be a Renaissance, and not just a Retro fad, there would almost have to be significant divergences between pre-teleport Incan civilization and the Karkalá, comparable to how Medieval Europe differed from Classical Greece and Rome. Time, separation from certain aspects of the home culture, pressures from the new setting (geography, climate, resources, wildlife, anyone else they might encounter along the way) are sufficient causes.

The Black Death's role in the coming of the Renaissance is not so clear-cut, but it did kill off a huge portion of the population, particularly in port cities and their biggest trade destinations, and it was a huge, unbeatable catachlism on a civilization-wide scale. People were dying in droves, nobody could do anything about it, and this was common knowledge. The reintroduction of lost texts to the popular consciousness, along with the gradual recovery from the plague (possibly due to all the resources it freed up) served as something of an antidepressant.

Ultimately, "Renaissance" is just a Romantic way of saying "Rebirth". Inject as much into the civilization you've established, mix with the things that have changed since the Teleport, and see where it leads.